# How do I get back an Outlook 2010 address book that is missing from TO: dialog?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, contacts, address-book

The following issue is with Outlook 2010 after an upgrade from Outlook 2007.  Not sure if the upgrade is the cause, but the user believes that to be the case.

In the list of contacts, we have a shared contact list (public folder) in the office.  One of the users can see the list when she clicks the Contacts button in the navagation pane.  But when she sends an email and clicks the "To:" button, the shared list is not shown in the "Address book" dropdown.

Why is it missing and how do we get it back?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Right click the address book in question (under Contacts) > Properties

On the tab "Outlook address book" tick the box "Show this folder as an address book"

Comment: That option is present for "regular" address books.  Not so for Public Folders.